# Could "system volume information" and $RmMetadata pose information leakage on a nuked HDD?

Tags: windows, hardware, data-leakage

I recently nuked my HDD(s) via a Windows program (Disk Wipe to be precise: http://www.diskwipe.org/), now everything is fine when I try to retrieve the information on that disk by any program I can find except for a couple of programs which have noted that the `$RmMetadata` folder still exists with files such as `$TxfLog.blf` within them.

An example image is shown below:

[image]

I have done a litle bit of searching to try and understand exactly what these files are but no one seems completely sure.

Could this data still existing pose information leakage problems for a nuked disk if I were to, say, sell it on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of `$TxfLog.blf` is self-explanatory: The extension [blf](https://www.openthefile.net/extension/blf) indicates a [CLFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_File_System) log file, and [TxF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS) stands for Transactional NTFS. You can see that TxF is just a temporary file that backs up transactions to help against sudden crashes, just like similar precautions in modern databases. There can exist some leakage from this file, but it only would consist of the last few transactions.

[System Volume Information](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031120-00/?p=41753) sounds innocent, but it can contain indexes for fast searching the files on the partition. Leakage is very likely here.

Although the method you've mentioned destroys most of the data, traces like these still can leak information about the original data. Most file systems can't be filled to 100%, so that writing files as long as writing is possible doesn't remove all traces. If you didn't like to use linux directly, you could use [DBAN](https://www.lifewire.com/dban-dariks-boot-and-nuke-review-2619130).

Comment: What if disk wipe has its own NTFS formatter built in? Could it then attack these inbetween sectors that could still possess data?

Comment: I guess so, but a far more easier (and reliable) way would be to overwrite [the drive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027) with zeroes and then create a new filesystem. The creator of disk wipe could have done just simply this. This is, for programmers, also possible on windows, not just on linux.

Comment: @Sammaye, if you want to assess that yourself, open up the drive forensically and see what the unallocated space contains (hint: it better be zeros!)

Comment: @MatthewPeters youmean physically put it under a microscope? Too bad that would void the warranty :(

Comment: @Sammaye, ha no, I mean use an imager and take a forensic image of the drive (like I did in my post). [Here](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2009/06/18/forensics-101-acquiring-an-image-with-ftk-imager/) is how to use FTK (its free).

Comment: @MatthewPeters ah I hadn't been able to fully look into that tool yet, I had been looking for something that could take a raw image rather than looking for file handles, thanks

Comment: @Sammaye, yeah FTK is great, there are other tools out there but I learned on FTK and that's my baby. If you want a super light-weight tool that also writes [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is perfect as well

Answer (score 3):

I was curious (and perhaps board) so I just ran a quick test to see... I took an old flash drive (4gb was my smallest one), did a quick reformat (to NTFS) and tossed a simple text file on there.

[Using FTK Imager](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2009/06/18/forensics-101-acquiring-an-image-with-ftk-imager), I took a before and after image of my drive (just the raw data dump). I used disk wipe to wipe (using the defaults and basic wipe settings) my test drive and then went to work trying to recover and review what was left behind.

After examining the remaining system files, I find that there is no way to reconstruct the original files themselves. The $Extend and $RmMetadata folders are simply system log files necessary for the file system and disk wipe to function properly, there is no useful recovery data stored in them.

I chose to write to zeros so I could quickly assess what is left behind but random values will work as well.

You can read up on NTFS [here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/New_Technology_File_System_%28NTFS%29) and data recovery [here](https://www.runtime.org/recoverability.htm). [Here](http://content.yudu.com/Library/A1rc90/Hakin9200906/resources/22.htm) is a post describing why the transactional files are there.

To answer your question, yes you can feel safe selling your securely wiped HDD.

You may be interesting in [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/115573/htg-explains-why-you-only-have-to-wipe-a-disk-once-to-erase-it/) article as it describes [the Gutmann method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method)

Comment: There is a discussion on this: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/is-it-ok-to-choose-an-accepted-answer-but-grant-the-bounty-to-an-other?cb=1

Comment: Despipte that discussion I was just too split so I did something I wasn't supposed to but meh

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly if Disk Wipe works by overwriting the partition data, or the disk data. If it only overwrites partition data, there can be files left on hidden partitions.

If you are confortable with Linux, it's very easy to nuke out a disk. Assuming your disk is on `/dev/sdb`, you could do this:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=65536 oflag=direct`

This will overwrite the entire disk with zeroes, effectively clearing all the data.

Comment: Disk wipe fills the entire disk, regardless of partitions with files each spanning 2GB of the algorithm you choose (in this case random byte) and then deletes those files in order to nuke the disk. I do know of Linux ways but my computer use makes windows ways easier for me. I have a feeling that these files left over are actually for the NTFS file system but I cannot be sure